# I need a function to return the first level parenthesized substring in python

Tags: python, string

I have been using a code to remove a parenthesized substring, which goes like this;

```
def alkylrem(j):
    removed = ''
    paren_level = 0
    for char in j:
        if char == '(':
            paren_level += 1
        elif (char == ')') and paren_level:
            paren_level -= 1
        elif not paren_level:
            removed += char
    return removed
```

But I find this inadequate since I also need to retrieve the parenthesized substring and maybe store it in a global variable. Can I add an 'elif' statement to do that? or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Could you add some example inputs and expected outputs? It's not clear what your strings will look like from your question as it is

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expressions pattern to extract the text inside the prenthesis and a different pattern to remove it.

```
import re

j = "some sentence (with) parnethesis"

def alkylrem(j):
    pat = re.compile(r'\((.*?)\)')  # pattern for getting the contents
    pat2 = re.compile(r'(?<=\().*?(?=\))') # pattern for removing the contents
    contents = pat.findall(j)   # finds whatever is in the parenthesis
    contents_remove = ''.join(pat2.split(j)) # removes contents
    return contents[0], contents_remove  # return both 

print(alkylrem(a))
```

output

```
'with', 'some sentence () parnethesis'
```

If you aren't familiar with regex, another method would be to simply find the index of the open and close parenthesis and reconstruct the string based off that.

```py
def alkyrem(j):
    opener = j.index('(')
    closer = j.index(')')
    contents = j[opener+1:closer]
    removed = j[:opener+1] + j[closer:]
    return contents, removed
```

Neither solution would work if you have nested parenthesis.

Comment: This doesn't handle nested parenthesis the same way as the OPs example.